# Read a resource from a helper class

Tags: java, xml, getresource

I am trying to code a helper class with methods that should read a XML file inside my resources folder and get some values on which I will work inside my main class. 
My project structure looks like this :

```
Project
|
|---src
|    |
|    |---Main.class
|    |
|    |---Helper.class
|
|---resources
     |
     |---MYDOC.xml
```

And the code for the Helper.class I came up with so far is:

```
public class HelperClass {


static Document document;
static XPath xPath;
```

public  HelperClass(){

```
  try {

       InputStream stream = HelperClass.class.getResourceAsStream("MYDOC.xml");

       DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

       document = builder.parse(stream);
       xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();     

      }
        catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (SAXException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } 

  };
```

static String getValue(){

```
String result = "";

String expression = "/SOMETHING/SOMETHING/VALUE";
try {
    result = xPath.evaluate(expression, document);
} catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return result;
```

}
}

I have set up the resources folder as a source folder, tried many combinations of the file path (/MYDOC.xml, resources/MYDOC.xml etc.) but I always get a NullPointerException when I try to use the getValue() method inside the Main.class.

I would be grateful if someone could explain me what I am doing wrong or a better way to solve this,  but I suspect that basically my whole code is bad.

To summarize: I would like to make a HelperClass that reads and gets values from a xml file and then use those methods inside another class.

Thank you in advance for any help/answer/critique.

Comment: Compile to a .jar file, and look into it with a zip utility. It should contain MYDOC.xml. If not resources must be a source folder in the IDE. If in the jar the path is resources/MYDOC.xml, use that as relative or absolute path "/resources/MYDOC.xml". And mind the case-sensitive writing.

Comment: Go to your class folder, are you able to see the xml file along with your .class files?

Comment: @JoopEggen Compiled it, the file is inside.

Comment: @saumikgupta File is inside the folder too.

Comment: Maybe `result` is null? I expected the InputStream, the XML resource null, not found. The stacktrace gives the source plus line number.

Comment: Nope, I dont even get a result, just a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

In your class path if the xml is within the resource folder try

```
HelperClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/MYDOC.xml");
```

If the xml is directly under the class path then try

```
 HelperClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MYDOC.xml");
```

Comment: Tried both options, with the file inside the resources folder and next to the class, I am still getting a NullPointerException when i use the method getValue() inside my Main.class.

Comment: What confuses me is when I place the whole Helper.class code inside one method (with a return type String added) everything works fine. But when I separate the code like above it throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: Is your Helperclass and Mian class is under same package? can you try this. Read the .xml as ResourceAsStream in your method where it works. And then pass the Stream to your helper calss method to do rest of the logic. Just a trial. Not a solution.